# How to configure JUnit 5 test-runner JVM in Gradle to enable incubator modules?

Tags: gradle, junit

In my `build.gradle.kts` I have, among other things:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(listOfNotNull(
        "--enable-preview",
        "--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.concurrent"
    ))
}

tasks.withType<JavaExec>() {
    jvmArgs!!.addAll(listOfNotNull(
        "--enable-preview",
        "--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.concurrent"
    ))
}

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOfNotNull(
        "--enable-preview",
        "--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.concurrent"
    )
}

tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    jvmArgs!!.addAll(listOfNotNull(
        "--enable-preview",
        "--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.concurrent"
    ))
}
```

My code that relies on `jdk.incubator.concurrent` compiles fine with `gradle compileJava`, and runs fine with `gradle run` — but when I try to use `gradle test`, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for the classes I'm trying to use.

Seemingly, the JUnit 5 test-runner JVM isn't inheriting the `jvmArgs` from the configuration in `Test`; nor from the configuration under `JavaExec`.

Every solution I've been able to find for enabling incubator modules in a project's JUnit tests, seems to be in the context of Maven projects rather than Gradle projects; and the solution provided there (passing `<arg>`s to `maven-surefire-plugin`) is no help, because Gradle uses its own internal test-runner logic. How do I do this in Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    jvmArgs("--enable-preview", "--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.concurrent")

    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
}
```

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/main/egg_StackOverflow_74397964)